# SQL View alias not working in H2 SELECT statement

Tags: database, select, view, alias, h2

I have a table `student` and a view `annual_performance`. I am creating a view `student_annual_performance` like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW student_annual_performance AS SELECT
s, ap
FROM student s INNER JOIN annual_performance ap ON s.id = ap.studentId;
```

This works fine in PostgreSQL but gives below error in H2 in-memory database

> SQL State  : 42S22 
>   Error Code : 42122
>   Message    : Column "ap" not found; SQL statement:

Answer (score 0):

You use an arcane PostgreSQL-specific feature that doesn't exist in other databases. You cannot use a table (view) name or its alias name as value expression in H2 and in the most of other databases.

You can use `… AS SELECT (s.column1, s.column2, …) s, (ap.column1, ap.column2, …) ap FROM …` instead in both databases, where `column1`, `column2` etc. are names of the columns in the table `student` and in the view `annual_performance` to get the same result.

You can also use `… AS SELECT * FROM …` to get all values in the separate columns.